# When does Limit-point compactness imply compactness or sequential compactness?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

It can be shown, for metric spaces, that the notions of compactness, limit-point compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent, yet these results can be made more general. In particular:

$$\text{compact} \Rightarrow \text{limit-point compact}$$
$$\text{compact} + \text{first-countable} \Rightarrow \text{sequentially compact}$$
$$\text{sequentially compact} \Rightarrow \text{limit-point compact}$$
$$\text{sequentially compact} + \text{second-countable} \Rightarrow \text{compact}$$

I am wondering:

1. **Which axioms of countability/separation are specifically needed for limit-point compactness to imply compactness?**

What I have found so far is a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116532/if-x-is-limit-point-compact-space-which-is-t1-then-x-is-countably-compact) that
$$T_1 + \text{limit-point compact} \Rightarrow \text{countably compact}.$$

2. **Which axioms of countability/separation are specifically needed for limit-point compactness to imply sequential compactness?**

I believe I remember -although I cannot seem to find where I read it- that
$$\text{first-countability} + T_1 + \text{limit-point compact} \Rightarrow \text{sequentially compact}.$$
What I have been able to find are [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594211/what-is-a-first-countable-limit-compact-space-that-is-not-sequentially-compact) of first-countble limit-point compact spaces that are *not* sequentially compact.

---

Whatever the answer to these questions are, I'd appreciate if a (link to a) proof is included (:

Comment: See [here](https://planetmath.org/relationshipamongdifferentkindsofcompactness)